# How to provide parameters to a class with static methods without changing the static qualifier on them?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static-methods

I have a class with static methods:

```
public class CompletelyStatic {

    public final static String PARAM = "abc";

    public static String doSomethingSpecial() {
        return "qqq" + PARAM;
    }

}
```

These methods are used everywere throughout the code. The new requirement is to load PARAM value from external config. This config is provided via Config object, through dependency injection, i.e.

```
public class CompletelyStatic {

    @Inject
    private Config configProvider;

    public final static String DEFAULT_PARAM = "abc";

    public String doSomethingSpecial() {
        return "qqq" + configProvider.getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, here I had to change static qualifier on doSomethingSpecial, so everywhere I used it, I have to inject a CompletelyStatic instance. I'd rather avoid that. I could probably do something like that:

```
public class CompletelyStatic {

    public final static String DEFAULT_PARAM = "abc";

    public static String doSomethingSpecial(Config configProvider) {
        return "qqq" + configProvider.getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
    }

}
```

But if doSomethingSpecial invoked some private methods underneath, I would have to propagate configProvider along. Is there a better solution?

Edit. If CompletelyStatic had some internal private methods, I should then propagate configProvider to them:

```
public class CompletelyStatic {

    public final static String DEFAULT_PARAM = "abc";

    public static String doSomethingSpecial(Config configProvider) {
        return "qqq" + otherMethod(configProvider);
    }

    private static String otherMmethod(Config configProvider) {
        return "more logic " + configProvider.getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
    }
}
```

Edit 2. To clarify, I have no influence on the Config object. I know it would be nice if it had static methods, but it doesn't.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, mainly the last section.. How does your private methods look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to do something like this:

```
public class CompletelyStatic {

    @Inject
    private Config configProvider;

    // Keep a static private instance of your Static class
    private static CompletelyStatic cs = new CompletelyStatic();

    //If needed, make the constructor of your class private
    private CompletelyStatic(){
    }

    public final static String DEFAULT_PARAM = "abc";

    public static String doSomethingSpecial() {
        return "qqq" + cs.getConfigProvider().getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
    }

    public Config getConfigProvider(){
        return configProvider;
    }
}
```

Your other private methods will be able to use the `configProvider` object in a similar manner: `cs.getConfigProvider()`

> **Update**

```
public class CompletelyStatic {

    public final static String DEFAULT_PARAM = "abc";

    //Keep a static reference to the ConfigProvider object.
    private static Config configProvider;

    public static String doSomethingSpecial(Config configProvider) {
        CompletelyStatic.configProvider = configProvider;
        return "qqq" + otherMethod(configProvider);
    }

    // Here, you will not need to parameterize your other methods.
    private static String otherMmethod() {
        return "more logic " + configProvider.getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this does help and seems the best solution. Feels like a hack, though - creating a singleton that can only be used within the same class. :)

Comment: I kind of want to rethink if maybe it's better to actually change my CompletelyStatic class to be actually a bean itself. But anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the configuration object must be  a static

```
public class CompletelyStatic 
{
    public final static String DEFAULT_PARAM = "abc";
    public static String doSomethingSpecial()
   {
        return "qqq" + Config.getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
    }
}
```

**or**

```
public class CompletelyStatic 
{
    private static String SPECIAL_PARAM = Config.getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
    public final static String DEFAULT_PARAM = "abc";
    public static String doSomethingSpecial()
   {
        return "qqq" + SPECIAL_PARAM;
    }
}
```

**or**

config should be a singleton instance in that case `Config.getInstance().getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The better solution can be loading `static` `Config` variable during application startup through an `init()` like method as shown in the below code. The advantage of this approach is that **you don't need to change/modify all of your dependent classes** if you are moving from `Config` to something else. Otherwise, you need to change all of your classes from where you are invoking `doSomethingSpecial()`.

```
public class CompletelyStatic {

       private static Config configProvider;

       //you need to load the below init method during application start up
       public static void init(Config configProvider) {
           CompletelyStatic.configProvider= configProvider;
       }

       public static String doSomethingSpecial() {
           return "qqq" + otherMethod();
        }

        private static String otherMmethod() {
           return "more logic " + configProvider.getSpecialParam(DEFAULT_PARAM);
       }
     }
```

Also, in this approach, the method signature `public String doSomethingSpecial()` did not change from the original class (so no effect to all of the dependent classes, but only point is to load `init` during start up).